# `import username from './username.txt'` with typescript+webpack gives `undefined`

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, import

I'm making a demo of importing .txt files as strings with typescript + webpack, almost done, but have this problem:

**hello.ts**

```
import username from './username.txt'

console.log(`Hello, ${username.trim()}!`)
```

Reports:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
```

My other files:

**txt.d.ts**

```
declare module '*.txt' {
    const value: string
    export default value;
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './hello.ts',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.ts?$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.txt$/,
            loader: 'raw-loader'
        }]
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "demo": "webpack && node bundle.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.9",
    "@types/node": "^10.10.3",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "7.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.0.3",
    "webpack": "^4.18.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

If I change the importing code in `hello.ts` as:

```
import * as username from './username.txt'

console.log(`Hello, ${username.trim()}!`)
```

It will have another type error:

```
console.log(`Hello, ${username.trim()}!`)
                               ^^^^^^
TS2339: Property 'trim' does not exist on type 'typeof import("*.txt")'
```

Although I can find a way to make it work:

```
const username = require('./username.txt')
```

But I still want to know how to fix it with the `import` style.

The demo project for this: https://github.com/freewind-demos/typescript-import-txt-file-as-string-issue-demo, you can clone and run it

Comment: as a debugging step, have you tried `console.log(typeof username)`

Comment: The process is all correct, the issue is likely in the `.d.ts`, since typescript is not aware that `username` is a string. You can workaround by doing (using import * as): `console.log(\`Hello, ${(username as any).trim()}!\`)`. Otherwise, you need to fill the type definition, but I have no idea how to do this. Using username as any will work, though: http://prntscr.com/kxz7ps (and won't throw any compile-related issue). Is there any reason you are doing the module declaration for the .txt file?

Comment: @briosheje, thanks for your answer. Yes, `username as any` works but not elegant, also loses the type checking. I do this because my test should run in browser, and I need to import some data from file as input in tests. I think there should be something wrong, but not sure where it is.

Comment: @Freewind is there any reason you are using a txt file for input purposes? Also, is there any reason why you need to declare the types? Wouldn't it be easier to use a JSON and parse it?

Comment: @briosheje The functions I want to test is to convert some text into another format, they are not JSON all the time, and can be pure text

Comment: @Freewind so is there any reason to have "typings" on them?.. I mean, they should be strings.. right?..

Comment: @briosheje Yes, they are just strings, but you have to make typescript type checking pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `raw-loader` is generating a module that has the text string as a CommonJS-style export assignment, not as a default export.  You should either update the type declaration and code to work with that:

```
declare module '*.txt' {
    const value: string
    export = value;
}

import username = require('./username.txt')
```

or enable the `esModuleInterop` compiler option in `tsconfig.json` to make default exports interoperable with export assignments.  You can read a little more about the issue [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#support-for-import-d-from-cjs-form-commonjs-modules-with---esmoduleinterop).

Comment: With the new `declare module '*.txt'`, I can write `import * as username from './username.txt` now! Thanks